# Create a unterminable process in Windows

Tags: windows

I am a student, and am genuinely curious about unterminable processes in Windows.

For educational purposes, I would like to create an application (possibly in VB6?) which cannot be terminable by a user from task manager or taskkill. What are some strategies and exploits that such applications employ to make this possible?

Comment: VB6 probably isn't going to get you there. That's a bit like saying you've heard about international cargo shipping, and you have a rowboat and would like to give it a try.

Comment: [This StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992671/how-to-write-an-unkillable-process-for-windows) question may help, and [this Technet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes.aspx) - their conclusion, you can't do anything useful with something *truly* unkillable. Anything is must use malware-type techniques (such as installing as a driver) to become harder to kill. You may also be interested in [how DRM does it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarForce).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Contrary to what a lot of people believe, there are actually several ways to do this. Some of them are common, some rarely seen. Some of them are weak, some strong. It all depends on how you do it.

Let's go through a collection of them:

---

**1. Pre-NT `RegisterServiceProcess` trick**
Windows 9x, and other pre-NT operating systems, had an undocumented API in kernel32.dll called `RegisterServiceProcess`, which (as the name suggests) registers the process as a system service. Once a process had called this function, the operating system considered it critical and would not allow task manager to kill it. This function was removed when NT came around, so it doesn't work on XP or higher.

**2. Process naming tricks**
Back in WinXP, the Task Manager executable contained a hard-coded list of process names that it would refuse to kill, instead displaying a message like the one you mentioned. These basically covered the critical system services such as `smss.exe` and `rpcss.exe`. The problem was that the path isn't checked, so any other executable with the same name would result in an un-killable process. This trick doesn't prevent the process from being killed, per se,  but rather stops the Windows XP Task Manager from being able to kill the process. It is still possible to use another tool to kill the process.

**3. Keep-alive processes**
These are by far the most common. Two processes are created, and repeatedly check for the other's existence. If one is killed, the other resurrects it. This doesn't stop you from killing the process really, but it does make it annoying to stop the process from coming back.

Task Manager includes an option to kill the process tree, which allows you to kill a process and all child processes, which may help fix this issue. When a process is created in Windows, the OS keeps track of the process ID that created it. Kill process tree iterates through all processes and looks for those who have a parent ID equal to the process ID that you're killing. Since keep-alive processes usually work on a repeated polling, you can kill both processes before they notice anything went wrong.

A defence against this is to create a dummy process that spawns the keep-alive process, then have that dummy process exit. The main process passes its ID to the dummy process, and the dummy process passes its ID to the keep-alive process, but the chain is broken when the dummy process exits. This leaves both the primary and keep-alive processes running, but makes it impossible to use Task Manager's kill process tree function. Instead, you'd have to write a script to kill them off, or use a tool that allows you to kill multiple processes simultaneously.

**4. User-mode hooks via loaded DLLs**
It is possible to [inject a DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection#Approaches_on_Microsoft_Windows) into a running process. In fact, Windows offers a feature to have any DLL loaded into all processes that import user32.dll, for the purposes of extensibility. This method is called AppInit DLLs. Once a DLL is injected, it may manipulate the memory of the process. It is then possible to overwrite the values of certain function pointers such that the call is redirected to a stub routine, which then calls the target function. That stub routine may be used to filter or manipulate the parameters and return values of a function call. This technique is called *hooking*, and it can be very powerful. In this case, it would be possible to inject a DLL into running processes that hooks `OpenProcess` and `TerminateProcess` to ensure that no application can gain a handle to your process, or terminate it. This somewhat results in an arms-race, since alternative user-mode APIs can be used to terminate processes, and it's difficult to hook and block them all, especially when we consider undocumented APIs.

**5. User-mode hooks via injected threads**
This trick works the same as with DLLs, except no DLL file is needed. A handle to the target process is created, some memory is allocated within it via `VirtualAllocEx`, code and data is copied into the memory block via `WriteProcessMemory`, and a thread is created in the process via `CreateRemoteThread`. This results in some foreign code being executed within a target process, which may then instigate various hooks to prevent a process being killed.

**6. Kernel-mode call hooks**
In the kernel, there's a special structure called the System Service Dispatch Table (SSDT), which maps function IDs from user-mode calls into function pointers in to kernel APIs. This table is used to transition between user-mode and kernel-mode. If a malicious driver can be loaded, it may modify the SSDT to cause its own function to be executed, instead of the proper API. This is a kernel-mode hook, which constitutes a rootkit. Essentially it is possible to pull the wool over the OS's eyes by returning bogus data from calls. In fact, it is possible to make the process not only un-killable, but also invisible. One issue with this on x64 builds is that the SSDT is protected by Kernel Patch Protection (KPP). It is possible to disable KPP, but this has far-reaching consequences that may make it difficult to develop a rootkit.

**7. Direct kernel object manipulation (DKOM)**
This trick also involves loading a malicious driver on the OS, but doesn't require alteration of the SSDT. Processes on the system are stored as `EPROCESS` structures in the kernel. Keep in mind that this structure is entirely version-dependant and is only partially documented by Microsoft, so reverse engineering is required across multiple target versions in order to make sure that the code doesn't attempt to read the wrong pointers or data. However, if you can successfully locate and enumerate through `EPROCESS` structures in the kernel, it is possible to manipulate them.

Each entry in the process list has an `FLink` and `BLink` pointer, which point to the next and previous processes in the list. If you identify your target process and make its `FLink` and `BLink` pointers point back to themselves, and the `FLink` and `BLink` of its siblings point to each other, the OS simply skips over your process when doing any housekeeping operations, e.g. killing processes. This trick is called unlinking. Not only does this render the process invisible to the user, but it also prevents all user-mode APIs from targeting the process unless a handle to the process was generated before it was unlinked. This is a very powerful rootkit technique, especially because it's difficult to recover from.

**8. Debugger tricks**
This is a pretty cool trick that I've yet to see in the wild, but it works quite well. The Windows debugger API allows any process to debug another, as long as it has the permissions to do so. If you use the debugger API, it is possible to place a process in a "debugged" state. If this process contains a thread that is currently halted by a debugger, the process *cannot* be killed by Windows, because proper thread control cannot be guaranteed during termination when the thread is blocked. Of course, if you kill the debugger, the process stops being debugged and either closes or crashes. However, it is sometimes possible to produce a situation where a chain of processes exist that debug each other in a loop. If each process halts a dummy thread in the next, none can be killed. Note that it *is* possible for a power user to manually kill other threads within the process, rendering it useless, but it still won't be killed.

**9. Windows 8 DRM**
This is a new one I've only heard of recently, but I don't know much about it. There was a bit of a rumour going around on Twitter about it, and I've seen snippets here and there on various technical sites, but I've yet to see any concrete research. I think it's still early days. Essentially, the story is that Windows 8 has a mechanism that allows "trusted providers" to register processes as DRM critical, preventing them from being killed or manipulated by the user. Some people have speculated that the mechanism for checking trusted providers is weak, and may be open to attack.< - <strike>Looks like this one was bogus. So much for the rumor mill!</strike>

Update: Harry Johnston pointed out in the comments that Windows 8.1 introduces [protected services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn313124(v=vs.85).aspx), which are designed to be used by AV and DRM to protect against being manipulated or attacked by lower-privileged code on the system.

**10. Tool manipulation**
This one has probably been used a lot in the wild, but I've never seen it done properly. Essentially this trick involves targeting specific tools, e.g. Task Manager, by editing the executables on disk in a way that alters functionality. This is very similar to the user-mode hook tricks I mentioned earlier, but in this case they persist on disk and have wider-reaching consequences than simple API hooking. Of course, one issue is that Windows File Protection (WFP) prevents alteration of certain critical system files, including the task manager. Amusingly, though, it is possible to alter the default task manager executable path via the registry. So, instead of messing with the task manager executable file, just dump your own version somewhere and make the OS use it.

---

All in all, there are plenty of ways to achieve this, with varying degrees of robustness. The above represents a majority of them, but isn't exhaustive. In fact, many of the tricks I described can be achieved in alternate ways, using different mechanisms or APIs to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @polnomial Can you just tell which is the polular one and is generally used by various virus and anti-virus softwares.

Comment: They're all equally possible, give or take.

Comment: This is a pretty great answer, but I'd be curious to see the minimum required privileges to accomplish each method, as they all require different levels.

Comment: @SteveS 1,2,3 can be done by any user, 4,5,8,9 require admin, 6,7 require admin and a way to bypass driver signing (disable it or use a signed driver), 10 depends on the ACL of the file you're trying to replace.

Comment: Do you have any links about Windows 8 DRM? It sounds horrifying.

Comment: Does #8 really require admin? And for #3, you can also break Kill Process Tree by having ProcA start ProcB which will start ProcC and then ProcB terminates (all before Task Manager is opened). Then C is its own root in the process "forest" and unrelated to A.

Comment: @mihi Yes, #8 requires admin, since debugging is a privileged operation. I mentioned the process chaining trick in the final paragraph of #3.

Comment: I was under the impression that you can debug a process ify you have Full Control permissions for it (like if it runs under your user account). At least I debugged some programs with OllyDbg without being an Admin (stuff like HW Breakpoints does not work though).

Comment: @mihi Yes, that is true, but I'm pretty sure that in this case the "debug a debugger" part requires admin.

Comment: Your #9 sounds suspiciously like [protected services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn313124(v=vs.85).aspx) which were introduced in Windows 8.1.  (Perhaps the rumours were correct, but the technology wasn't ready in time for the original release of Windows 8?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Nice find. I'll include it in the answer.

Comment: Just in case this answer is removed, I save the page :)

Answer (score 8):

I do not believe that what you are trying to do is possible.  You would have to subvert the OS to prevent a process from being able to be killed.  All processes run within the OS, therefore the OS can kill any process.  You can even kill processes like "explorer.exe" which is what runs the start menu and desktop.

Most programs that appear to be "unkillable" are actually killable, but another program is monitoring their execution and when it sees the process get closed, it will automatically be restarted immediately.  When you kill processA, processB starts it and when you kill processB, processA starts it.  Since you can't easily kill both processes exactly together, it becomes very difficult to get rid of them while the system is running.

This same technique is used by several anti-virus vendors as well as the popular anti-cheating program PunkBuster.

It is also possible, on older systems, that the process may be running as a service.  In Windows XP and Windows 2000, the Task Manager is not able to kill processes that were started by the service manager as the service manager runs under a different user context.  On these older systems, creating a Windows Service would be resistant to direct killing with Task Manager, however newer versions of Windows will allow it to be killed.

It may be useful to see what context the process is running under if permission is denied.  You can use a tool like Process Explorer from the SysInternal's suite to see what user context the process is running under.  If the user context that Task Manager is running under does not have access to kill processes running under the user context that the process is running under, then the kill will fail.

Related information is available on super user under this question https://superuser.com/questions/109010/kill-a-process-which-gives-access-denied.  It appears that there is a per process security setting that can be applied to remove the right to kill.  This could be done programmaticly and would complicate killing it, however an administrator could still take ownership of the process and then adjust the permissions back to allow killing it.  The particular windows APIs are CreateProcessWithTokenW and SetSecurityInfo.

Comment: Don't consider my intention wrong but I have seen my viruses that are impossible to terminate from task manager.

Comment: @VarunDotCuDotCc - what is generally happening there is that there are two executables.  Each monitors the other and when one is killed, the other restarts it immediately.  Since the files can be locked while the executables are running, you can't simply delete them without stopping both first.  This technique is frequently used by AV software as well as the popular anti-cheating program Punkbuster.

Comment: No, there is a single executable. I am pretty sure. When I click on terminate procees option, I get the message "The process cannot be terminated" in task manager.

Comment: And then anti-virus does magic and process get termiinated (after a scan)

Comment: @VarunDotCuDotCc - Are you trying to kill the "application" or the "process."  If UAC is on, are you running as admin or user?  If you are running at a user level, you won't be able to kill administrative processes.  Also, when killing at the "Application/Task" level, the process is asked to close and it can refuse.  Killing the process itself should hard stop the process regardless of its wishes.

Comment: OK, I have a proof. Install AVG Anti Virus(can be free). Now move to process tab in task manager and choose to terminate the process avgnt.exe Do you know what you will get, only a message "The operation could not be completed. Access is denied"

Comment: @VarunDotCuDotCc - If you are getting an Access Denied message, you almost certainly have UAC on and are not running task manager in administrative mode.  Do you have a "Show Processes for All User's button?  If so, click it (task manager will close and reopen automatically in administrative mode) and then try killing the process.

Comment: @VarunDotCuDotCc - the other possiblity is that if you get something called a rootkit, it could replace Task Manager with a fake or altered version or could alter Window's system files such that instructions to kill the process are ignored.  Such a program could not be made in Visual Basic however as it requires some very advanced native code programing to hijack that functionality and VB6 is far too limited to do this.  Legitimate programs are also unlikely to use a root kit as they can compromise a computer.  (See the Sony DRM RootKit fiasco.)

Comment: OK, I tried running task manager as administrator and everything you told. Also, I think UAC not exists in XP.

Comment: I think rootkit are not created by anti-virus. Have you checked installing AVG yourself

Comment: @VarunDotCuDotCc - Ok, I did a little more research on the message you got.  It appears that Task Manager is also not allowed to kill services.  If a process is started from the Service manager, it needs to be killed by the service manager or some other process killer.  You could make a service with VB6.  Also, sorry about the confusion.  I have not worked with XP in some time and the access that Task Manager has was changed between XP and Vista.  I'm fairly certain it can kill services directly now, but in XP/2000 it couldn't.

Comment: altering Window's system files such that instructions to kill the process are ignored.        this is what i am looking for

Comment: I just created a service in VB6, install and run it. After this, I terminated it very easily from task manager.

Comment: @AJHenderson I work with a lot of XP machines at our company, and I can confirm this message does come up when trying to kill specific tasks in Task Manager, even when you are logged in as the Administrator (I've also encountered this error on Windows 7 too, even with Run As Administrator). It's not all Services though, only some of them. Also, this error isn't just limited to system processes, even though its mostly system processes that won't let you kill them.

Comment: @Rachel You can see I am trying to convey the same thing from last 45 minutes. Now, I have some votes on my arguements. Generally, this technique is used by viruses and anti-virus to prevent them from being terminated by the other one.

Comment: It 2:45 AM here and I've spented a few hours here without any luck. So, I going to sleep and will join the discussion later.

Comment: @Rachel - do you have active directory running and are the processes run by a context that the local administrator does not have control over?  Ultimatly, the execution context is the key thing here.  Windows (unless rootkitted or very rarely, the kernel is made unstable) can kill any process that is running.  The access is denied messages are a result of the execution context of Task Manager not having permission to kill applications running under the execution context of the process.

Comment: @AJHenderson Yes, we use Active Directory and I know I've seen that error a few times when trying to kill a process from the network Administrator account, not just the local Admin account. Sometimes it's system processes, other times it's 3rd party programmers like AVG, and once or twice it's been Malware. Its not a problem I'm experiencing now so I probably would be no use at running tests, but I can confirm it's happened in the past :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/109010/kill-a-process-which-gives-access-denied - This has more details about process user contexts.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by AJ, the OS is ultimately in charge. It decides if a process can be killed, when it gets kill, how, etc. Certain processes may be "protected" by the os, preventing them from being terminated, or as is also the case, the process may be technically killable, but killing the process triggers a shutdown of the whole machine.

If you were writing malware and wanted to make it impossible to kill a process, then your best bet to do so would be to modify the OS to prevent it. This isn't out of the question, and is actually something authors have already thought about. In fact, making OS modifications to protect resources is such a common thread that they have a name for it: "[rootkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit)".

So how do you modify the running operating system? Luckily modern OSes are all written to allow you to make such modifications; just write a kernel module (a.k.a. "driver"). There's even a [development kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) to get you started.

Once you're there, just hook the code path that handles process control and put in your little exclusion rule. Read up on rootkits for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a truly unkillable process is not a good idea. It is however perfectly possible to protect a process from being terminated by any other user than an administrator. Administrators have, and should have, full access to the process and they can kill the process.

The way to do it is to modify the process ACL in order to have the OS refuse any attempts to kill the process by non administrators.

In your process starup code, you should obtain the process DACL, add a restriction to it so "Everyone" will get an "Access denied" when trying to kill the process, and then write back the process DACL.

I could provide you with .NET source code on how to do it, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has been overlooked here is the concept of (ab)using virtualisation to implement a hypervisor above windows containing your code.

As your code then runs outside and above windows it is not easily detectable, nor can be terminated by windows.

"[Blue Pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_(software))" was a proof of concept of such a concept, however after some initial fuss such an implementation is very rarely mentioned and personally I've yet to see such a thing in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 5 ways.

1. Have a signed kernel driver and run your process as protected through it. (the most recommended)
2. Use `RtlSetProcessIsCritical()` in `ntdll.dll` to flag your process as a critical system process.
3. Make 2 processes. If one terminates the other one starts it.
4. Use System Exploits to gain Kernel Privilges or load an unsigned kernel driver.
5. This technique is being used by usermode rootkits. It hooks functions in task manager (some rootkits even hook all processes that they can hook not task manager alone) and the function it hooks is `TerminateProcess` to return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if it tried to terminate your process. If it wasn't your process then it will continue with termination normally. I don't recommend this technique because a lot of AV's will flag it as a rootkit.